# Keras / Tensorflow not utilising all CPU cores

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a rather straightforward script for training and validating. I'm using `tensorflow-gpu` and I can see `GPU:0` being used. However, the `python` process itself appears to be using just a single core with just around 90% utilisation. My GPU isn't getting maxed out during training either. It gets fully utilised during validation, however.

I wonder whether the use of a single core is preventing the GPU from being utilised more. Is there a way to use more CPU cores? I've tried setting `config.intra_op_parallelism_threads = 4`, but still only a single core is used.

Here's my script:

```py
import model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from visual_callbacks import AccLossPlotter
import numpy as np


def main():
    np.random.seed(45)
    nb_class = 2
    width, height = 224, 224

    sn = model.SqueezeNet(nb_classes=nb_class, inputs=(3, height, width))

    print('Build model')

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=0.0002, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    sn.compile(
        optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(sn.summary())

    # Training
    train_data_dir = 'data/train'
    validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
    nb_train_samples = 2000
    nb_validation_samples = 800
    nb_epoch = 500

    #   Generator
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)
    #train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_dir,
            target_size=(width, height),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical')

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_data_dir,
            target_size=(width, height),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical')

    # Instantiate AccLossPlotter to visualise training
    plotter = AccLossPlotter(graphs=['acc', 'loss'], save_graph=True)
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=0)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(                                         
                    'weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',
                    monitor='val_loss',                               
                    verbose=0,                                        
                    save_best_only=True,                              
                    save_weights_only=True,                           
                    mode='min',                                       
                    period=1)                                         

    sn.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
            nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples, 
            callbacks=[plotter, checkpoint])

    sn.save_weights('weights.h5')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    input('Press ENTER to exit...')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not utilize both CPU as well as GPU simultaneously. When you are using GPU for computation, your CPU not doing the actual computation, it is only doing the book-keeping job for GPU kernels. And for doing book-keeping, CPU does not have to utilize all the cores (single core is enough).

**My GPU isn't getting maxed out during training either. It gets fully utilised during validation, however.**

That is because during training you are calculating the gradients and doing back-prop which are not massively parallel processes compare to simple forward pass(you have to update weights after every batch forward pass). And so those can not fully utilize the GPU. But during the validation you only calculating the forward pass and that is why during validation GPU's are fully utilized.

Although you may get more GPU utilization if you increase the batch_size.

Comment: I see. Since back-prop leaves quite a bit of spare capacity on the GPU, does that mean a more powerful GPU won't improve performance substantially then? Mine is a 1050 Ti.

Comment: Yes there are not enough parallel running tasks which utilizes your GPU.